# Unable to connect to MemoryStore instance (GKE, Node.js)

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

My Redis host is `'10.0.0.x'`, port is `6379`, and I made sure my k8s cluster which hosts Node.js pods and MemoryStore are in the same region, but it still times out when trying to connect.

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis({
    port: 6379,          // Redis port
    host: '10.0.0.x',   // Redis host
})
redis.on('connect', () => console.log('connected'))
```

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to enable VPC Native Alias IP in the Kubernetes Engine dashboard.

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips

Comment: To make this a good answer, in your answer, explain why you needed to enable VPC Native Alias IP and the steps to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the loop on this. The need for IP alias is documented here
https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance

IP alias makes Pod IP addresses are natively routable within the GCP network including peered networks.
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips